# RecyleView does not display items when List is from parse

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple RecycleView which its row includes a cardView.
Im querying Data from parse, and when I am passing it to the RecyleView's adapter it does not display the items.

I tried to check whether the List from Parse is empty( `Log.e("**" , Date_fromParse)` show me the data ), I tried to pass another list that I created manually, and it showed the items in the RecycleView in that case.
I don't think that the problem is in the row or in the RecycleView or in the adapter, but it might be somehow in the list itself that I pass to the adapter.
Any ideas what is the problem, and why it shows me nothing?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SongsRcAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


   public List<SongModel> mSongsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

         mSongsList = new ArrayList<SongModel>();

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Song");
        query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> songs, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
//                   made it i<2 to test if it is because the size. still not displayes the items
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        ParseObject object = songs.get(i);

                        String songName = object.getString("name");


                        String poetName = object.getString("poetName");


                        Date dateSong = object.getDate("pushDate");


                        String LetterOfTheDate = Utils.DateToFirstDayletter(dateSong.toString());
                        String DateToNumbers = Utils.toNumbersDate(dateSong);

                        SongModel s = new SongModel(poetName, songName, LetterOfTheDate, DateToNumbers);

// Checked whether it saves it. it is.
//                        Log.e("*********************", s.getPoet() + " " + s.getDayOfSong() + " " + s.getPushDate() + "  " + s.getSongName());

                        mSongsList.add(s);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("error", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

// if I pass the adapter this list, it shows it.
//        List<SongModel> songsslist = new ArrayList<>();
//        SongModel s = new SongModel("t","t","t","t");
//        songsslist.add(s);

        mAdapter = new SongsRcAdapter(mSongsList, getApplicationContext());

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class SongsRcAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongsRcAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<SongModel> songsList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView poetName, songName, LetterDate, NumbersDate;
        private CardView cardView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            poetName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.poetName);
            songName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songName);
            LetterDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.letterDate);
            NumbersDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateNumbers);

            cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

        }


    }

    public SongsRcAdapter(List<SongModel> songsList, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.songsList = songsList;
    }

    @Override
    public SongsRcAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.linetest, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.poetName.setText(songsList.get(position).getPoet());
        holder.songName.setText(songsList.get(position).getSongName());
        holder.LetterDate.setText(songsList.get(position).getDayOfSong());
        holder.NumbersDate.setText(songsList.get(position).getPushDate());

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songsList.size();
    }

}
```

Row

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:dividerPadding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="songName"
                android:id="@+id/songName"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/letterDate"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="L"
                android:id="@+id/letterDate"
                android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="poetName"
                android:id="@+id/poetName"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/dateNumbers"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dateNumbers"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="11.01"
                android:id="@+id/dateNumbers"
                android:layout_below="@+id/letterDate"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/letterDate"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ContentMain (it included in activity_main)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="shirapp.israel.nir_zabari.shira.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Images:

With tha fake list.

[image]

what it actually shows me.

[image]

Comment: just call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after loop where you add new object into list

Comment: why can't it be done the way I did it, outside the loop? @Alexander
P.S Problem solved

Comment: I saw that problem was fixed.
may be it help you in future. loop is finished after adapter is set in listview. So the adapter doesn't know that data was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happenening because your Parse's done() is called after you initialize your adapter in :

mAdapter = new SongsRcAdapter(mSongsList, getApplicationContext());

So, what you can do is, createa method changeData in your adapter to change the your data and in your Parse's done() method, call that method to change the data:

```
done(Exception e){
  ...
  //After Populating your list
  mAdapter.changeData(mSongsList)
  ...
}
```

And in your adapter:

```
public void changeData(ArrayList<Song> list){
  songsList = list;
  notifydataSetChanged();
}
```